# Struts2 and Ajax Call Failure for Token

Tags: ajax, struts2, yui, token

I have an application with Struts 2 and YUI. A page is populated to display few Groups (A.jsp) and this page contains a  tag. When I am clicking any button on this page, it is invoking some url and works fine. But when I am using some Ajax call from this page (submitting the form data as well), it raises a "Token not found" exception.

```
YAHOO.util.Connect.setForm(formObject);    
YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('GET', url+'?'+parameter, callback);
```

The behavior is not consistent i.e. some times it is raising this exception, sometimes runs properly.

Any idea on this?

Comment: Anybody...need help really !!

Comment: Is your url for request is relative or absolute?

Comment: @AMI: it is relative url